# Counterexample for measure and some property of nonmeasurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

Suppose that $A ⊆ E ⊆ B$, where $A$ and $B$ are Lebesgue measurable subsets on $R^n.$ If m(A) = m(B). Give an example showing that the same conclusion does not hold if A and B have infinite measure, then $E$ is measurable.

I can't find an example like that, I know if A and B have infinite measure, then axioms of equality will fails. Thus, we can't get $E$ is measurable.

---

Another one of mine question is that the union of two nonmeasurable is measurable or nonmeasurable? Or both be possible?

If we consider Vitali set, we have $R=V∪V^∁$. Therefore, it is measurable. Will it always true for all case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: Take $A=(0,\infty), B=\mathbb R$ and $E=A\cup F$ where $F\subset (-\infty, 0)$ is non-measurable.

Second question: Consider the union of a non-measurable subset of $(0,1)$ and a non-measurable subset of $(1,2)$.

Comment: Thus, for second question, both are possible right? Since we can have the example you give and I write above.

Comment: Yes, you gave an example where the union is measurable and I gave an example where it is not.

Comment: Thank you for help.